# Linux is consuming lot more menory than RSS output

Tags: linux, memory-leaks

Below are the output of `free -g` and `ps -aux`. `free` indicates 35G of RAM being used, but I don't see how the `ps` output might be showing me what processes exactly are consuming the most memory.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            54         35         18          0          0          1
-/+ buffers/cache:         34         20
Swap:            8          0          8


[opc@lapp203 ~]$ ps -aux
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  19416  2316 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:01 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:16 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:03 [rcuos/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [rcuob/0]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [migration/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [migration/1]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:02 [rcuos/1]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [rcuob/1]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [watchdog/2]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [migration/2]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/2:0H]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:03 [rcuos/2]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [rcuob/2]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [watchdog/3]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [migration/3]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/3:0H]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:02 [rcuos/3]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [rcuob/3]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [watchdog/4]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [migration/4]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/4]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/4:0H]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:03 [rcuos/4]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [rcuob/4]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [watchdog/5]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [migration/5]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/5]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/5:0H]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:02 [rcuos/5]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [rcuob/5]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [watchdog/6]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [migration/6]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/6]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/6:0H]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:08 [rcuos/6]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [rcuob/6]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [watchdog/7]
root        56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [migration/7]
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/7]
root        59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/7:0H]
root        60  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:02 [rcuos/7]
root        61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [rcuob/7]
root        62  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [khelper]
root        63  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        64  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [netns]
root        65  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [perf]
root        66  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        67  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [writeback]
root        68  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Mar17   0:00 [ksmd]
root        69  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Mar17   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [crypto]
root        71  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        72  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bioset]
root        73  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kblockd]
root        74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [md]
root        76  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [kworker/0:1]
root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        91  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        92  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
root        94  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:02 [kworker/2:1]
root        95  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root        97  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bcache]
root        98  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [deferwq]
root        99  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [kworker/1:1]
root       100  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [kworker/3:1]
root       101  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:08 [kworker/5:1]
root       102  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:01 [kworker/6:1]
root       103  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:02 [kworker/7:1]
root       138  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [iscsi_eh]
root       182  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       319  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       320  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root       321  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root       326  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [ib_addr]
root       327  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [ixgbevf]
root       328  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [iw_cxgb3]
root       332  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [iw_cm_wq]
root       333  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [iw_cxgb4]
root       334  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [cnic_wq]
root       335  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bnx2i_thread/0]
root       336  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bnx2i_thread/1]
root       337  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bnx2i_thread/2]
root       338  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bnx2i_thread/3]
root       339  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bnx2i_thread/4]
root       340  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bnx2i_thread/5]
root       341  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bnx2i_thread/6]
root       342  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bnx2i_thread/7]
root       549  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       550  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
root       551  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [iscsi_q_2]
root       552  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [scsi_wq_2]
root       631  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/5:1H]
root       638  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/2:1H]
root       639  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:01 [jbd2/sda3-8]
root       640  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       647  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/7:1H]
root       649  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/6:1H]
root       651  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root       653  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/4:1H]
root       721  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/1:1H]
root       746  0.0  0.0  11608  2744 ?        S<s  Mar17   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       769  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kworker/3:1H]
root       815  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kworker/6:2]
root      3351  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [kauditd]
root      3394  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [ib_mcast]
root      3395  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [ib_nl_sa_wq]
root      3396  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [ib_cm]
root      3397  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [rdma_cm]
root      3398  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [rdma_cm_fr]
root      3406  0.0  0.0  24936 18768 ?        S<Lsl Mar17   0:00 iscsiuio
root      3412  0.0  0.0   4996  1520 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:03 iscsid
root      3413  0.0  0.0   8624  4536 ?        S<Ls Mar17   0:12 iscsid
root      3622  0.0  0.0   9176  2212 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -H phxalc5lapp203 -1 -q -lf /var/lib/d
root      3672  0.0  0.0  27776  1788 ?        S<sl Mar17   0:00 auditd
root      3706  0.0  0.0 245128  2804 ?        Ssl  Mar17   0:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
root      3721  0.0  0.0  18312  1884 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:07 irqbalance --pid=/var/run/irqbalance.pid
root      3736  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [scsi_eh_4]
root      3737  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [scsi_tmf_4]
root      3738  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [iscsi_q_4]
root      3739  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [scsi_wq_4]
rpc       3776  0.0  0.0  19040  1928 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 rpcbind
rpcuser   3800  0.0  0.0  23412  2456 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 rpc.statd
root      3832  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [rpciod]
root      3837  0.0  0.0  23160   192 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 rpc.idmapd
dbus      3863  0.0  0.0  29980  2620 ?        Ssl  Mar17   0:00 dbus-daemon --system
root      3885  0.0  0.0 189144  6488 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 cupsd -C /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
root      3909  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [kdmflush]
root      3910  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [bioset]
root      3927  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [nfsiod]
root      3939  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [nfsv4.0-svc]
root      3941  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [jbd2/dm-0-8]
root      3942  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root      3954  0.0  0.0   4156  1636 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
68        3966  0.0  0.0  37216  5688 ?        Ssl  Mar17   0:00 hald
root      3967  0.0  0.0  20456  2796 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 hald-runner
root      4005  0.0  0.0  22576  1060 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 hald-addon-input: Listening on /dev/input/event1 /dev
68        4010  0.0  0.0  18060  2108 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 hald-addon-acpi: listening on acpid socket /var/run/a
root      4011  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [kworker/5:2]
root      4095  0.0  0.0  66316  2552 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
ntp       4108  0.0  0.0  30800  4240 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g
root      4199  0.0  0.0  81012  6240 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 /usr/libexec/postfix/master
postfix   4216  0.0  0.0  81264  6312 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
root      4217  0.0  0.0 116892  2480 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 crond
root      4236  0.0  0.0  21164   216 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
root      4260  0.0  0.0  35512  5600 ?        Ssl  Mar17   0:03 /opt/Tanium/TaniumClient/TaniumClient
root      4294  0.0  0.0 200940 12048 pts/1    Ss+  Mar17   0:23 /usr/local/qualys/cloud-agent/bin/qualys-cloud-agent
root      4306  0.0  0.0   4124  1356 tty1     Ss+  Mar17   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
root      4308  0.0  0.0   4124  1332 tty2     Ss+  Mar17   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
root      4310  0.0  0.0   4124  1404 tty3     Ss+  Mar17   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3
root      4313  0.0  0.0  12528  3744 ?        S<   Mar17   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      4314  0.0  0.0   4124  1304 tty4     Ss+  Mar17   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4
root      4316  0.0  0.0   4124  1192 tty5     Ss+  Mar17   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
root      4318  0.0  0.0   4124  1344 tty6     Ss+  Mar17   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
root      6092  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:00   0:00 [kworker/3:0]
root      7272  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar17   0:00 [kworker/1:2]
root     11979  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kworker/4:0]
root     19550  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kworker/2:0]
root     23050  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kworker/4:2]
root     23146  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root     26106  0.1  0.0 963224 28744 ?        Sl   02:47   0:07 /opt/Tanium/TaniumClient/TaniumClient -c
root     26636  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:13   0:00 [kworker/u16:2]
postfix  26651  0.0  0.0  81092  6260 ?        S    03:16   0:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u
root     27085  0.0  0.0  97992  6324 ?        Ss   03:34   0:00 sshd: arwadmin [priv]
arwadmin 27093  0.0  0.0  97992  5200 ?        S    03:34   0:00 sshd: arwadmin@pts/3
arwadmin 27103  0.0  0.0 108380  3196 pts/3    Ss+  03:35   0:00 -bash
root     27176  0.0  0.0  97992  6204 ?        Ss   03:40   0:00 sshd: opc [priv]
opc      27184  0.0  0.0  97992  3440 ?        S    03:40   0:00 sshd: opc@pts/4
opc      27185  0.0  0.0 108380  3180 pts/4    Ss   03:40   0:00 -bash
root     27223  0.0  0.0  97992  6232 ?        Ss   03:42   0:00 sshd: ppdsoa [priv]
ppdsoa   27231  0.0  0.0  97992  4944 ?        S    03:42   0:00 sshd: ppdsoa@pts/5
ppdsoa   27246  0.0  0.0 108512  3260 pts/5    Ss   03:42   0:00 -bash
root     27445  0.0  0.0  97992  6216 ?        Ss   03:47   0:00 sshd: ppdsoa [priv]
ppdsoa   27450  0.0  0.0  97992  3316 ?        S    03:47   0:00 sshd: ppdsoa@pts/0
ppdsoa   27451  0.0  0.0 108512  3264 pts/0    Ss+  03:47   0:00 -bash
ppdsoa   27480  0.0  0.0 218936 41004 pts/0    Sl   03:47   0:00 /usr/bin/Xvnc :3 -desktop phxalc5lapp203:3 (ppdsoa) -
ppdsoa   27496  0.0  0.0  50276  4556 pts/0    S    03:47   0:00 vncconfig -iconic
ppdsoa   27500  0.0  0.0 253768 13700 pts/0    Sl   03:47   0:00 gnome-session
ppdsoa   27503  0.0  0.0  20120  1980 pts/0    S    03:47   0:00 dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session
ppdsoa   27504  0.0  0.0  29948  2476 ?        Ssl  03:47   0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address
root     27508  0.0  0.0  49992  4976 ?        S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/devkit-power-daemon
ppdsoa   27512  0.0  0.0 132684  6732 ?        S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
ppdsoa   27531  0.0  0.0 555020 17812 ?        Ss   03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon
ppdsoa   27533  0.0  0.0 161828  3772 pts/0    Sl   03:47   0:00 gnome-keyring-daemon --start
ppdsoa   27536  0.0  0.0 284460 15120 ?        Ss   03:47   0:00 seahorse-daemon
ppdsoa   27540  0.0  0.0 137452  4544 ?        S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
root     27547  0.0  0.0  11604  2404 ?        S<   03:47   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
ppdsoa   27551  0.0  0.0 266860 17700 pts/0    S    03:47   0:00 metacity
ppdsoa   27557  0.0  0.0 358344  5640 ?        Ssl  03:47   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
rtkit    27559  0.0  0.0 164412  2064 ?        SNl  03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/rtkit-daemon
root     27563  0.0  0.0  52524  6172 ?        S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-1/polkitd
ppdsoa   27564  0.0  0.0 594280 33776 pts/0    S    03:47   0:00 nautilus
root     27566  0.0  0.0 4114656 5080 ?        Sl   03:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
ppdsoa   27635  0.0  0.0 253444 14628 pts/0    S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gdu-notification-daemon
ppdsoa   27638  0.0  0.0 446432 20304 pts/0    S    03:47   0:00 gnome-volume-control-applet
ppdsoa   27640  0.0  0.0 257924 15892 pts/0    S    03:47   0:00 bluetooth-applet
ppdsoa   27644  0.0  0.0  30328  6884 pts/0    S    03:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/restorecond -u
ppdsoa   27654  0.0  0.0 255876 14104 pts/0    S    03:47   0:00 gnome-power-manager
root     27656  0.0  0.0  45532  5144 ?        S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/udisks-daemon
root     27662  0.0  0.0  45268   316 ?        S    03:47   0:00 udisks-daemon: not polling any devices
ppdsoa   27669  0.0  0.0 144080  5424 ?        S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.8 /org/gtk/gvfs
ppdsoa   27674  0.0  0.0 146468  5928 ?        S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
ppdsoa   27679  0.0  0.0 230680  5128 ?        Sl   03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
ppdsoa   27682  0.0  0.0 151056  5116 ?        S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
ppdsoa   27687  0.0  0.0 135276  4420 ?        S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-metadata
ppdsoa   27691  0.0  0.0 137480  4940 ?        S    03:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-burn --spawner :1.8 /org/gtk/gvfs/
root     27696  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:48   0:00 [kworker/u16:1]
ppdsoa   27873  0.0  0.0 114740  3188 pts/5    S+   03:54   0:00 vi /u01/ppdsoa/CSDW/Oracle/Middleware/oracle_common/c
root     27989  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:55   0:00 [kworker/u16:0]
opc      28141  2.0  0.0 110256  2284 pts/4    R+   03:58   0:00 ps -aux
root     28233  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kworker/7:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you look in the `man` page for `ps` you'll discover that your output is in fact already displaying everything you want to know...

   ```
   VSZ       virtual memory size of the process in KiB
             (1024-byte units).  Device mappings are currently
             excluded; this is subject to change.  (alias
             vsize).

   RSS       resident set size, the non-swapped physical
             memory that a task has used (in kiloBytes).
             (alias rssize, rsz).
   ```
2. You can help yourself out by using the `--sort` option of the `ps` command to sort on `vsz` and `rss`, in conjunction with the `head` command. For example:

   ```
   ps aux --sort -rss | head
   ```
3. You can also tell `ps` exactly what and how you want it displayed, and then pipe the output to `awk` to convert the numbers into a form easier to read:

   ```
    ps -eo pid,vsz,rss,comm --sort -rss,-vsz | head \
    | awk 'NR>1 {$2=int($2/1024)"M";$3=int($3/1024)"M"}{ print;}' \
    | column -t
   ```